# Symfony: custom filter/hook/eventlistener - how to?

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I'd like to achieve:

- Listen to `myController->myAction()` and
- call `myService->myModification()` (before)
- to filter/modify the `$item` (`listenToMyFilterBefore` / `listenToMyFilterAfter`)

Pseudocode below. Seems to be a mix of [event listening](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and [filtering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html). What's a good practice?

```
class myController() {
    public function myAction() {
        $item = new Item();          
        $item = registerFilter('listenToMyFilterBefore', $item); // possibility to prepare before

        // ... some modification ...

        $item = registerFilter('listenToMyFilterAfter', $item); // possibility to modify after

        // ...
    }
}

class myService {
    public function myModification() {
        // listen to "myController->myAction"

        $item = filter('listenToMyFilterBefore', function($item) {
            $item->setLockMe(true);
        });

        $item = filter('listenToMyFilterBefore', function($item) {
            $item->setLockMe(false);
            $item->setSomeValue('myValue');
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make myService a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html and access it from your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the standard Symfony2 events suits to your needs: listener `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` to call before the controller execution and `KernelEvents::VIEW` to call after.

Also apply to FrameworkExtraBundle. It should help you to get instance of the Item before the controller code. Your listener could be fetched right after ExtraListeners.

Controller is not obliged to return `Response` instance. If you will return `Item` then `KernelEvents::VIEW` event will be dispatched. You could process `Item` in the corresponding listener and return `Response`. Look for `FOSRestBundle` and `ViewResponseListner` for the similar floor.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

If this is not enough you could also apply to `AOP` approach.
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSAopBundle